# break on symbol use in gdb (cpp)

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a cleaner (preferably gdb only) way to do the following (Setting breakpoints on every line in the code where a certain pattern appears),

```
grep ~/work/proj some_var_or_pattern -Irni| cut –f1,2 –d":" | sed –e 's/^/b /' > ~/moo.txt
```

and load the results with

```
(gdb) source ~/moo.txt
```

Comment: Probably not. But as an alternative to source-ing you could simply do `gdb -x ~/moo.txt` ...

Comment: You can make it more convenient by putting it into a shell script, then in gdb use `define` to create a new command that will use `shell` to run the script (pass it `$arg0`) and then `source` the file full of breakpoint commands.

Comment: I would edit it both with a comment that it should probably be done from / so that the file would contain an abs path as well as reversing the grep arguments which I somehow got wrong, in case somebody else wants to use it. (But I don't have enough reputation on this site)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that's the solution I'm going with, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb doesn't do that by itself, but you can put your grep and break command generating code into a shell script and call it from gdb with a single command.

Put this in a file in your $PATH as, say, `greptobp`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: greptobp pattern dir outputfile
pattern="$1"
dir="$2"
outputfile="$3"
if [ "${dir#/}" = "$dir" ]
then
    # if dir isn't absolute, make it absolute, as requested by OP
    dir="$PWD/$dir"
fi
grep -HIirn "$pattern" "$dir" |
    awk -F: '{ print "break \"" $1 "\":" $2; }' > "$outputfile"
```

and add this to gdb:

```
(gdb) define patbreak
Type commands for definition of "patbreak".
End with a line saying just "end".
>shell greptobp $arg0 $arg1 /tmp/gdbtmp
>source /tmp/gdbtmp
>shell rm /tmp/gdbtmp
>end

(gdb) document patbreak
Type documentation for "patbreak".
End with a line saying just "end".
>Set breakpoints at lines matching specified pattern in a specified directory.
>Usage: patbreak pattern dir
>end
```

Comment: Just added the define into .gdbinit and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: BTW, instead of using the if, you could replace dir="$2" with dir="$(readlink -m $2)" (Probably should quote $2 as well but I'm not sure if a simple \"$2\" is good enough?)

Comment: Sure, if you're on GNU/Linux, it's shorter to use `readlink -m`.

Answer (score 2):

## rbreak (unfortunately only for functions).

Unfortunately there is no build in command for setting breakpoints on all lines matching certain pattern. But there are build in commands for seting breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expressions:

`rbreak regex` and  `rbreak file:regex` ([short tutorial](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html)).

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm familiar with rbreak (I've accepted the answer that there's no such built-in feature).